# Why is wordpress generating random <br> and staggering my images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

First i'd like to point out i'm a relative css noob. I know my way enough around to read code, but not do much with it.

http://quickfire-games.com/wild-season/

This is the page i'm trying to edit. As you can see the console logos, are staggered/stepped. I have no idea how to fix this, and I believe we are having the same problem on our home-page as well. From what I can tell wordpress is introducing these br's between the images.

I tried adding a local

```
<br><br>
       style br display: none; /style
<br><br>
```

which fixed the problem, but removed subsequent br's from the page (resulting in the paragraph text in the following line, being inline with the text.

This is the closest i've gotten to fixing it, with attempts at display:inline in the surrounding

doing nothing (I'm assuming for my purposes using an enclosing p should work fine? or do I really need to use a div?)

Comment: Doesn't look like the link to your site worked...

Comment: Sorry, the url should be http://http://quickfire-games.com/wild-season/

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, If you are editing a page in the Wordpress control panel then every time you create a new line in the textarea, Wordpress is swapping the newline break with `<br>` tags.

In Drupal, you can  change the settings of how your work is output. My suggestion is go to the settings and see if you can change the output.

Comment: I originally was, however I switched into html mode to tweak the alignment of my images, since in the WYSIWYG editor it was adding weird breaks and stuff, so I tidied it up in the wordpress html editor. Currently all the img tags sit in the same line within the same p tags with no breaks between them. Yet when the webpage is saved and rendered, lo & behold, the br tags appear :(

Comment: Hi Sharan, I checked out your page in multiple browsers (Opera, Chrome, Safari, Firefox) and I didn't see the issue you were talking about. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Hi guys, yes, I just changed the modules i used, thanks!